# LINQ groupby question

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a collection called `navigationList`. This list holds `customer` objects.
A customer has a property called `Town`.

The list holds 5 customers: 2 with town "New York", and 5 with town "Madrid".

I want the list to only hold only 2 customers. 1 with town "New York" and one with "Madrid". If 2 are from "New York", I want the last one. Same for "Madrid".

What would the LINQ statement look like?

```
var newList = navigationList.GroupBy(c => c.Town) // ?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would want something like

```
var newList = navigationList.GroupBy(c => c.Town).Select(g => g.Last()).ToList();
```

However, you would probably want to `OrderBy` first, so that the `Last` is meaningful:

```
var newList = navigationList.
              GroupBy(c => c.Town).
              Select(g => g.OrderBy(c => c.Id).Last()).
              ToList();
```

In this case the ordering is done by customer Id.